# How to configure xml code style in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I wanted to define few formatting styles for the XML in Android Studio. I found it under Settings-Editor-Code Style-XML. I thought that Arrangements tab could help me. But I have no idea how to put them to work. I searched if there were docs but couldn't find nor any questions asked about it anywhere.

For example here is an unformatted  XML --->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
             <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
             <corners android:radius="4dp" />
             <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"></solid>
             <gradient android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:endColor="@color/colorAccent" android:angle="45"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

while I want the formatter to format something like this, when I press 'Ctrl+Alt+L' --->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >


    <item>            
        <shape>

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
                />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"
                >
            </solid>
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

So, can you show me how to configure the Arrangements tab to achieve custom format? Or is this not the right way?
Thank you.

TO UPDATE:
    Thank you for suggesting 'Ctrl+Alt+L', but I know that and my question is about customizing the code style of Xml formatter given under Arrangements tab as I mentioned above.

Comment: **CTR** + **ALT** + **L**

Comment: @Nkoyee I'm not  sure what u wanted to do as the above two codes are the same only in item tag android:state_pressed="true" is absent so plz elaborate

Comment: @SnehalGongle I am talking about the code formatting of Xml, like we do in Java with 'Ctrl+Alt+L".  I found that under 'Settings-Editor-Code Style-XML' there is 'Arrangements' tab where we can define our new rules for formatting Xml. But I don't know how to work with the syntax there. And also the above two codes are not same for their code-style format.

Comment: Here is a blog post about formatting xml https://medium.com/@VeraKern/formatting-xml-layout-files-for-android-47aec62722fc You can also select in Editor > Code Style > XML > Other > Wrap Attribute -> Wrap Always

Answer (score 4):

For your example with the `<selector>` in xml, it looks like the arrangement doesn't need to be changed, as the elements are already in the order you want them to be.

To change the formatting, go to Preferences --> Editor --> Code Style --> XML, and click on the "Android" tab.  Change the "Wrap attributes" value (under the "Value Resource Files and Selectors" heading) from the default of "Do not wrap", to "Wrap always".  Click OK.

[image: Android Studio XML preferences for Android]

Now, if you do a reformat via **CMD + ALT + L** or **CTRL +ALT + L** on the selector xml, it will produce the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"></solid>
            <gradient android:angle="45"
                      android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                      android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

It's not exactly as you desired, but at least the attributes have their own line, which aids readability.

Comment: The given "Wrap always" may give the xml attributes their own line, but I was looking if Xml Configurations in Android Studio allows more than that. Which seems isn't the case. The xml formatting is quite limited than the code formatting.